# php 実行中に git コマンドを使用して tag名を取得したい

Tags: php, git

Ubuntu上のApacheサーバーで、phpによりサイトを作成しています。

phpの処理の中で、`exec("git tag " , $out , $ret);` としてtag名を取得したいのですが、最近のgitでセキュリティが厳しくなったのか、以下のエラーになります。（古いバージョンでは出ていなかった）

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/var/www/server/hoge'
```

エラーの意味は分かるし、コマンドを実行している時でしたら `git config --global safe.directory <ディレクトリパス>` で解消するのは分かります。

しかし、phpの実行中は www-data ユーザがこのコマンドを実行することになるので、Ubuntu上にログインできる www-data ユーザはいません。
www-dataユーザを作って その ~/.gitconfig に safe を追加するのが正解なのでしょうか？
他に方法があったら教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

最初 www-data ユーザを作成して ~/.gitconfig に safe.directory を設定したのですがダメでした。
少し時間をおいて冷静に考え、git の[ドキュメントページ](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)で、以下の記述を見つけました。

> 最初に Git が見るのは /etc/gitconfig で、ここにはシステム上の全ユーザーの全リポジトリ向けの設定値を記述します。 git
> config にオプション --system を指定すると、このファイルの読み書きを行います。

そこで、

```
sudo git config --system safe.directory /var/www/server/hoge
```

を実行することで、実行中のphpからでも git tag コマンドがエラーなく実行できました。
エラーになった理由は不明ですが、もしかするとgitのバグかもしれませんね。